# Redefine Retake function in UIIMagePickerController use custome overlayview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I use custome overlay view in UIIMagepickercontroller and set

```
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

So after take picture, it's not have Retake button and I create toolbarbuttonitem "retake"but I don't know how to recall UIImagepickercontroller when pressed retake button.

I had create custom overlayview and then add toolbarbuttonitem in it. I use follow codes :

```
- (void)retakePressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"retakePressed...");
    // TODO: take picture!
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

When i using bellow codes, it call Viewcontroller not uiimagepicker
Can you help me?  Thanks in advance